# first scanf gets other chrachters for the next scanfs

Tags: c, scanf

I'm making a simple calculator in C and I want the program to show the message "Enter an operator!" when the user enters something that isn't an operator, enter, space or tab. but if the user enters a number like 123 the message is shown 3 times instead of once. how can I fix this?

```
char op;
printf("please choose an operator (+,-,*,/): ");
while (op!='+' && op!='*' &&op!='-' &&op!='/' )
    {
    if (op!='\n'&& op!= '\t'&& op!=' ')
    printf ("Enter an operator!\n");
    scanf ("%c",&op);
    }
```

Comment: Use `getchar()` instead.

Comment: Also, you need to get your first char before you enter the `while` loop.  Otherwise, `op` is unassigned, and undefined behavior results.

Comment: If the user types "`ab`" do you want one error message or two? If the user types "`..`" do you want one error message or two? If the user types "`!$`" do you want one error message or two?

Comment: It might be simpler overall to read a *string* (using `%s`) rather than a single character.  Or perhaps an entire *line* of text (using `fgets`).  Then call `strlen` to see if it's one character long. (Also [strip the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776) if you used `fgets`.)

Comment: Also, what if the user types "`++`"?  Should that get an error message, and if so, how many?

Comment: When you get to the bottom of it, this ends up being a question about [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).  (And a search for a truly proper answer would reveal that `scanf` is simply not the right tool for the job.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scan set could be used `%1[+-/*]` will scan one character in the set of operators.
If the character is not in the set, `scanf` will return `0`. Clean the input stream and try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    char op[2] = "";
    int result = 1;

    printf ("Enter an operator!\n");
    do {
        if ( result != 1) {
            printf ("Enter an operator!\n");
        }
        result = scanf ( "%1[+-/*]", op);
        if ( result == EOF) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "EOF\n");
            return 1;
        }
        int clean = 0;
        while ( ( clean = fgetc ( stdin)) != '\n') { // clean input stream
            if ( clean == EOF) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "EOF\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    } while ( result != 1);

    printf ( "operator %s\n", op);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters use the format string `" %c"` to enter a character. Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'`.

Pay attention to that you are using an uninitialized variable op in the condition of the while loop that results in undefined behavior.

```
char op;
printf("please choose an operator (+,-,*,/): ");
while (op!='+' && op!='*' &&op!='-' &&op!='/' )
//...
```

A simplified approach can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

char op;
printf("please choose an operator (+,-,*,/): ");
const char *operations = "+*-/";

while ( 1 )
{
    int result = scanf( " %c", &op );

    if ( result == 1 && strchr( operations, op ) != NULL )
    {
        break;
    }

    if ( result == 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%*[^\n]" );
    } 

    printf ("Enter an operator!\n");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

1st thing first. 1 rule I learned is that a function only do 1 thing.
In your case, `scanf("%c", &op)` is being called multiple times.
Put the `scanf()` between the `while()` loop and `printf()` and retry.
You can use a `do{...}while;` loop too.